# Products won't save after Upgrade to 1.7.0.2

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, upgrade

I recently upgraded a clients website from 1.5.0.1 to 1.7.0.2 and I have noticed I am getting the following error message when trying to save a product. I am stumped as to how I would fix this. 
My Upgrade process included a fresh install of Magento which updated the old DB.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`clientupgrade/catalogrule_group_website`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CATRULE_GROUP_WS_RULE_ID_CATRULE_RULE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`)
>   REFERENCES `catalogrule` (`rule_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CA)

I hope you guys can help.

Comment: Is it exact message which you get? `clientupgrade/catalogrule_group_website` doesn't look like a valid table name in magento db.

Comment: clientupgrade is the DB name.

Comment: Looks like inconsistent data. Some FK were added during the upgrade process, but you have inconsistent data in those tables. Do some selects and see orphan records and delete them.

Comment: I think you should write your comment as answer and accept it, for people who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys. I got it fixed. Turned out catalogrule_product and catalogrule_product_price had rule_id's that were not in catalogrule. I truncated catalogrule_product and catalogrule_product_price and applied the rules again via the admin to regenerate them.